# GitLab one pipeline per commit (instead of push)

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab

In our GitLab we have a repo with a CI/DI pipeline setup. However, what I noticed is that the pipeline runs once per push and not once per commit. Let us say your push included 3 commits, but you want to deploy the first commit, how can you do this?

Because the pipeline instance will on the last of the 3 commits and you would be able to deploy the last commit, but what happens if you wanted to deploy the first commit in the batch of commits you pushed. How to handle this situtation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create different branches for `development` and `deploy`
2. Change the pipeline to run on the `deploy` branch
3. Only merge what you need from `development` to `deploy`

Comment: You are suggest the git workflow which GitLab suggests: Dev branches, Feature branches and Deploy branches, correct? Currently we are using Git Flow (dev/master/feature), but we might think about your suggestion. It seems like it is a very small change: master just becomes deploy.

Comment: Yes, that sounds pretty much the same.

Comment: After doing some thinking I think we will take this approach, since this git workflow is not too much different than what we originally were gonna do and plus since GitLab supports this workflow, it we are using GitLab, it would be easier.